# How to change the default values when add link Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

In Add Link page, is it possible to change the default values like title, address, show these links to, by using URL parameters? 
According to [this](https://www.eliostruyf.com/add-the-my-links-functionality-as-in-sharepoint-2007-to-your-2010-site/), it seems possible in sharepoint2010. Does anyone know whether it works in 2013??

If not, is it possible to add a link by post REST API??

Comment: @chandrashekharjoshi Sorry. I'm a newbie. What do you mean by "add js to your master page"? Could you tell me which page? Or how could I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved by the steps below.

1. Add a custom action. Just follow the steps [here](https://www.eliostruyf.com/adding-a-custom-action-to-a-callout-in-sharepoint-2013/).

   In my case code is as below

   SP.SOD.executeFunc("callout.js", "Callout", function() {
           var itemCtx = {};
           itemCtx.Templates = {};
           itemCtx.BaseViewID = 'Callout';
           // Define the list template type
           itemCtx.ListTemplateType = 101;
           itemCtx.Templates.Footer = function(itemCtx) {
               // context, custom action function, show the ECB menu (boolean)
               return CalloutRenderFooterTemplate(itemCtx, AddCustomAction, true);
           };
           SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(itemCtx);
       });

   ```
   function AddCustomAction(renderCtx, calloutActionMenu) {
       // Add your custom action
       calloutActionMenu.addAction(new CalloutAction({
           text: "FAVORITE",
           // tooltip: 'This is your custom action',
           onClickCallback: function() {
               CreateCustomNewQuickLink(renderCtx.CurrentItem.FileLeafRef, renderCtx.CurrentItem.FileRef);

           }
       }));

       // Show the default document library actions
       CalloutOnPostRenderTemplate(renderCtx, calloutActionMenu);
   }

   function CreateCustomNewQuickLink(title, url) {
       var urlAddress = $(location).attr('protocol') + "//" + $(location).attr('host') + '/_Layouts/quicklinksdialogformTEST.aspx?Mode=Link' +
           '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(title) +
           '&url=' + encodeURIComponent(url);
       ShowNewQuicklinkPopup(urlAddress, PageRefreshOnDialogClose);
   }
   ```
2. Create a new add link page which is copied from "quicklinksdialogform.aspx". I add some javascript as below.

   $(init)

   ```
   function init() {
       var args = new Object();
       args = GetUrlParms();
       if (args["title"] != undefined) {
           $(".ms-long")[0].value = decodeURIComponent(args["title"]);
       }
       if (args["url"] != undefined) {
           $(".ms-long")[1].value = decodeURIComponent(args["url"]);
       }
   }

   function GetUrlParms() {
       var args = new Object();
       var query = location.search.substring(1);
       var pairs = query.split("&");
       for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
           var pos = pairs[i].indexOf('=');
           if (pos == -1) continue;
           var argname = pairs[i].substring(0, pos);
           var value = pairs[i].substring(pos + 1);
           args[argname] = unescape(value);
       }
       return args;
   }
   ```
3. It works like below

[image]
[image]